# Incrementing the financial quarters in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, logic

I have the below sample input data with quarterly updates. I want to add this quarter data to the previous quarter table as shown in the output. I tried in Many ways but not able to find the right way.

Input DF:

`FIRST
2007Q1
2007Q1
2007Q1
2007Q2
2007Q2
2007Q2
2007Q3
2007Q3
2007Q3
2007Q4
2007Q4
2007Q4
2008Q1
2008Q1
2008Q1`

Output:

`First    Last
2007Q1  2006Q4
2007Q1  2006Q4
2007Q1  2006Q4
2007Q2  2007Q1
2007Q2  2007Q1
2007Q2  2007Q1
2007Q3  2007Q2
2007Q3  2007Q2
2007Q3  2007Q2
2007Q4  2007Q3
2007Q4  2007Q3
2007Q4  2007Q3
2008Q1  2007Q4
2008Q1  2007Q4
2008Q1  2007Q4`

Can someone help me in solving this in python. I need this to perform further analysis. Thanks!

Comment: What is the dtype?

Comment: dataframe and a char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column is a string, convert it to a `Period` object:

```
df['FIRST'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.FIRST, freq='Q')
```

Next, use `pd.PeriodIndex.shift`:

```
df['LAST'] = df['FIRST'].shift(-1)
```

```
df

     FIRST   LAST
0   2007Q1 2006Q4
1   2007Q1 2006Q4
2   2007Q1 2006Q4
3   2007Q2 2007Q1
4   2007Q2 2007Q1
5   2007Q2 2007Q1
6   2007Q3 2007Q2
7   2007Q3 2007Q2
8   2007Q3 2007Q2
9   2007Q4 2007Q3
10  2007Q4 2007Q3
11  2007Q4 2007Q3
12  2008Q1 2007Q4
13  2008Q1 2007Q4
14  2008Q1 2007Q4
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it as a one-liner:

```
df['LAST'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['FIRST']) - pd.DateOffset(months=3),freq='Q')
```

Comment: My answer is also a one liner and shorter ;) `pd.PeriodIndex(df.FIRST, freq='Q').shift(-1)`. The point is, one liners are overrated.

Comment: True that. Just wanted to add diversity to the answers. I voted for your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function to do this:

```
def last_q(c):
    sp = c.split("Q")
    yr = sp[0]
    q = sp[1]
    if int(q) > 1:
        return "Q".join([yr,str(int(q)-1)])
    else:
        return "Q".join([str(int(yr)-1),"4"])
```

For example:

```
>a = pd.Series(["2017Q1", "2016Q4"])
>a
0    2017Q1
1    2016Q4
dtype: object

>a.apply(last_q)
0    2016Q4
1    2016Q3
dtype: object
```